# Access elements within forms in c#

Tags: c#

I'm designing an application having an MDI parent form and three child forms namely Courses, Students and Teachers. The courses form consists of a textbox and submit button. After clicking the submit button the course entered in the textbox should appear in a new textbox on the same form. I'm able to do this once but after one textbox is created if I enter one more course and click submit, then another textbox is not created. I have used list to create textbox. The problem is I'm not able to access the list object defined in Courses form in the Students form. Can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can get reference to Courses from Students through MdiParent property of child form:

```
        var parent = this.MdiParent;
        // set proper index
        var index = 0;
        var child = parent.MdiChildren[index];
        // then you can get list object
```

About problem with textbox creation, post you code please.